# trouble with strcmp() in C

Tags: c, strtok, strcmp

```
char* mystr = calloc(25, sizeof(char));
fgets(mystr, 25, stdin); // I enter "6 7 *" in here, without the quotes

char* tok;
tok = strtok(mystr, " ");
while (tok != NULL) {
    if(strcmp(tok, "*") == 0)
        //It never meets this condition, but I don't understand why
    else
        //do something else here
    tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

The problem is that the `strcmp(tok, "*")` never returns as being equal, even though `tok` reads in the asterisk from the original string. I don't understand why it never meets this condition.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger (like `gdb`). Maybe try with `strncmp(tok, "*", 1)`

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger, line by line, and see what `strtok` returns.

Comment: Not only is `sizeof(char)` 1, it's better not to repeat the `char` unnecessarily: `TYPE *ptr = calloc(N, sizeof *ptr)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `*` token is likely also containing the `\n` character you typed to complete your input.  Either compare a single character with one of:

```
  if(tok[0] == '*')

  if(strncmp(tok, "*", 1) == 0)
```

or add `\n` to your separator list:

```
  tok = strtok(NULL, " \n");
```

Comment: I just used your exact program and both of these changes fixed it fine.  You must not be showing us something important.

Answer (score 0):

Because fgets is embedding the newline character into the variable mystr. This is throwing off the comparison. Try to remove "\n" from variable.

Answer (score 0):

The `strcmp()` compare two strings. You have to provide * as a string with the terminating character `"*\n"`.

```
if(strcmp(tok, "*\n") == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another input for you.
strtok() is not thread safe. Be careful while using. If you are having multiple threads(both calling strtok() for some purpose), use strtok_r().